# cannot reach readystate=4

Tags: javascript, ajax, readystate

I go this AJAX code that worked fine, but when I moved it to a new file it stopped working.
I managed to find out that the readystate isn't 4 and status isn't 200.
The code was given to my in class by the teacher. It worked find until I made new file.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var request = false;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
 else if (window.AciveXObject)
request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");


  function login(PhpFile,divId,frm)
  {
if (request)
{
    var obj = document.getElementById(divId);
    request.open("POST",PhpFile);
    //setting the header
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-   urlencoded');

    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {   
        if (request.readyState == 4 &&
                request.status == 200){
            obj.innerHTML =request.responseText;
        }
        else
        {
         alert("here");
        }
    }

    request.send("log="+frm.log.value+"&pwd="+frm.pwd.value);
} 
}


</script>
```

Comment: Remove the space between `www-form-` and `urlencoded`. Also, specify the `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you `alert(request.responseText)` in that `else` case, that may give you more information

Comment: Found the problem, wasn't with this code after all... It was just some stupid typo at the target php file...

Comment: glad you found it -- not sure whether that would have shown up in responseText

Answer (score 0):

```
'application/x-www-form-   urlencoded'
```

should be

```
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```